# CSS float issue, float right is clearing my other floats but there is no float:clear

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm making a title bar, links on the left, center, and the right. Each separated by divs.

Floating left is no problem, centering the second div is no problem. But when I try to float the last div to the right it is clearing the other divs and is not inside my header. Why is this? It has to be something simple I am missing? Thank you very much

http://jsfiddle.net/GX9xn/

HTML

```
 <div class="header-fixed">
        <div class="header-container"> 

            <div class="nav-float-left">
              <div id="search">
                  <span>search</span>
              </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="nav-center">
                <a href="">title</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nav-float-right">

                  <a>
                        <span>more</span>
                  </a>                   
             <div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.header-fixed {
    height:56px;
    border-top: 1px solid #222;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
    position: fixed;
}
.header-container {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 56px;
}


.nav-float-left {
    float:left;
    height: 56px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .55);
    font-family:'Museo Sans W01 300',san-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .95);
    filter: dropshadow(color= rgba(0, 0, 0, .95), offx=0, offy=1);  
}


.nav-center {
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 43px;
    width: 100px;
    padding-top: 13px;
    background: black;
    color: #d4d2d2;
    font-size: 29px;
    font-family: “Lucida Grande”, sans-serif; 
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .57);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .57);
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .57);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .57);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-center .ss-pika {
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-right: 0px;

}
.nav-center a {
    display:block;
}

.nav-float-right {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    height: 55px;
    width: 205px;
}
```

Comment: `.nav-center` pushes it down.See this fiddle when I make it an inline block : http://jsfiddle.net/GX9xn/2/

Comment: than? you, making it an inline-block helps too, but now the class .nav-center is not centered, how would I adjust the css to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The center div will be above the float right div because it is a block element and block elements are not placed inline.

A walk around is to add the float-right element first.

```
<div class="nav-float-left">
    <div id="search">
        <span>search</span>
    </div>  
</div>
<div class="nav-float-right">
    <a><span>more</span></a>                   
<div>
<div class="nav-center">
    <a href="">title</a>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, that is great to know, it places my right float inside the header. But now the .nav-center class is broken and not centered, please see the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GX9xn/5/

Comment: Thank you very much, but when I tried it I see something different. What is different in my fiddle and yours? http://jsfiddle.net/Q2m7k/

Comment: You have a mistake... HTML line 12 replace <div> to </div>

Answer (score 2):

If you use float you also need to set the display property in order to do as you want.
I changed your fiddle by adding `display:inline-block`.

As you may notice you need to set the dimensions `width` for your divs (height optional).

Here : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rT5sW/)

Comment: This is a way better way to do your CSS. floats take your elements out of the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:table;` , `display:table-cell;` instead of floats to arrange elements in single line:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GX9xn/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.nav-float-right {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    height: 55px;
    width: 205px;
    bottom: 57px;
    left: 12px;
}
```

You can adjust the right div by set the `bottom` and `left` attributes.

Fiddel: http://jsfiddle.net/GX9xn/6/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GX9xn/7/)

There is slight change in your CSS file

```
.nav-float-right {
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    height: 55px;
    width: 205px;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    background: #fff;
}
```